# How to use hasField but for paragraph fields?

Tags: 8, 9, theming

Within a page template, how could I check if a paragraph field if present?

I'm using this and it works:

```
$node->hasField($field_paragraphfield)
```

But how can I modify this to look for a field *within* that field?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$node->hasField($field_paragraphfield_banner)
```

Comment: A node's paragraph field can hold multiple different paragraph **entities** (a paragraph is a full scale entity, not just a simple field. The node's paragraph field is just a pointer to that entity). And each of those paragraph entities can have a completely different field structure, e.g. the first might not have the field, but the third and the fourth might have this field.

Comment: To check the field on the **first** entity, use `$paragraph = $node->get('field_paragraph')?->entity; if ($paragraph?->hasField('field_banner')) {...}`